# get nginx to play nicely with php-fpm in docker

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to setup docker with nginx and php-fpm but it seems like there's something going wrong with regards to nginx conf (I don't know what exactly).

Here's `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  php:
    image: php:7.1-fpm
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    networks:
      - web

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - php
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/web.conf:ro
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    networks:
      - web

networks:
  web:
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name localhost;

  index index.php index.html;
  root /var/www/html/code;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;

    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

`./code/index.php`

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And then on the terminal

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here but when I visit `http://localhost:8000` I get the nginx welcome page instead of what's within `code/index.php`.

Can anyone help? Thanks

P.S: I am running the latest docker desktop on a mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/web.conf:ro
```

NGINX comes with conf.d/default.conf. Since you are not deleting it, you should at least overwrite it:

```
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
```

Since you are not doing this, NGINX still load default.conf and that is why you see the default homepage.

An extra issue: when you do your mapping this way, your nginx.conf ends up in /var/www/html. Even if you don't serve this location in your conf file, I would still suggest to avoid doing this. You could map your volume like `./code:/var/www/html`. Even better, I would remove completely this mapping from the nginx service since it is not needed.